# Location of background image is wrong

Tags: java, image, swing, jlayeredpane

I am trying to create a BackgroundImage class that has the purpose of creating a background with several image layers, I am using a JLayeredPane to achieve the layers.

The background image will hold a permanent base image and will have methods that allows me(hopefully) to fade in and out images upon this base image.

Right now i'm stuck at the base image being located wrong.

Here is a image that shows the problem:

[image: Image showing the problem with the location]

As you can see in the image, there is a slight grey area above the image that is not supposed to be there. I would like the base image to take all the space.

Here is a MCVE:

**BackgroundTest class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

final class BackgroundTest extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BackgroundTest();
}

BackgroundTest() {
    JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    BackgroundImage bgImage = new BackgroundImage(contentPanel);

    add(contentPanel);
    setSize(getScreenDimension());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static Dimension getScreenDimension() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    Rectangle bounds = ge.getMaximumWindowBounds();
    return new Dimension((int) bounds.getWidth(), (int) bounds.getHeight());
}
}
```

**BackgroundImage class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

class BackgroundImage {

    private final BaseImage baseImage;
    private final JPanel targetPanel;
    private final JLayeredPane layeredPane;

    BackgroundImage(JPanel targetPanel) {
        this.targetPanel = targetPanel;
        layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        Dimension screenDimension = BackgroundTest.getScreenDimension();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(screenDimension);
        layeredPane.setMaximumSize(screenDimension);
        layeredPane.setMinimumSize(screenDimension);

        baseImage = new BaseImage();
        layeredPane.add(baseImage, new Integer(0));

        targetPanel.add(layeredPane);
    }

    public void addCharacterImageToBase(int characterIdentifier) {

    }

    public void replaceCurrentCharacterImage(int characterIdentifier) {

    }


    private class BaseImage extends JComponent {
        private ImageIcon imageIcon;
        private int imageWidth, imageHeight;

        BaseImage() {

            BufferedImage backgroundImage;
            try {
                Dimension screenSize = BackgroundTest.getScreenDimension();
                imageWidth = screenSize.width;
                imageHeight = screenSize.height;
                setBounds(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/background/sky.jpg"));
                if (imageWidth > 0 && imageHeight > 0) {
                    backgroundImage = Scalr.resize(backgroundImage, Scalr.Method.QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, imageWidth, imageHeight, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
                }
                imageIcon = new ImageIcon(backgroundImage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Main.getLogger().log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }

        public int getImageWidth() {
            return imageWidth;
        }

        public int getImageHeight() {
            return imageHeight;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(imageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight, this);
        }
    }

    private class CharacterImage extends JComponent {

        CharacterImage(int currentLevelNumber) {

        }
    }
   }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: override getPreferredSize for JPanel (not for JComponent, take from  getScreenDimension() { minus JFrames bounds) then call pack for JFrame

Comment: JPanel is ImageObserver, then you can use getHeight/Weight from getPreferredSize instead of imageWidth, imageHeight

Comment: @mKorbel I don't understand. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that your JPanel has a BorderLayout by default and its hgap and vgap are not 0.

You need this:

```
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0,0));
```

Comment: contentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));

Do you mean like this? It dosent seem to solve the issue.

Comment: Edited again for simplicity